# Dagger 2 injection returns null in Activity scope

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I need to inject a dependency that requires FragmentManager in the constructor. In order to do that, I have created a custom scope for my activity linked to the MainModule of the app. After the injection, the dependency returns null. I think the problem is in submodules because the App dependencies work fine.

The code is the following:

**HomeModule**

```
@Module
public class HomeModule {

private HomeActivity homeActivity;

public HomeModule(HomeActivity homeActivity) {
    this.homeActivity = homeActivity;
}

@Provides
public BackStackManager provideBackStackManager(){
    return new BackStackManager(homeActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
}
}
```

**HomeScope**

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface HomeScope {
}
```

**HomeComponent**

```
@HomeScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {HomeModule.class})
public interface HomeComponent {
    void inject(HomeActivity activity);
}
```

**ApplicationClass**

```
public HomeComponent plusHomeComponent(HomeModule homeModule){

    if (homeComponent == null){
        homeComponent = mainComponent.plusHomeComponent(homeModule);
    }

    return homeComponent;
}
```

Comment: Try to use `@HomeScope` for your provide method `provideBackStackManager`.   `@Provides @HomeScope public BackStackManager provideBackStackManager()`

Comment: I have already try that but nothing changed. I am adding injecting the activity like this:         ((ApplicationClass)getApplicationContext()).plusHomeComponent(new HomeModule(this));